# emacs-w3m Buffer Navigation Tree

Tags: w3m

I need to go several URLs' back, because if I just hit B, which takes me to the last URL I visited in this buffer, I get right back to where I started, because it's a redirect;)

So, how can I manage to get further up the buffer navigation tree?;)

, or maybe it's buffer navigation chain, cause I don't think w3m stores the history as a tree.

I have a w3m-history, but this seems like a global history, not a buffer history.